# Unable edit a file (in Linux VM) non-interactively from pipeline (through Python script)

Tags: python, linux, bash, file, azure-pipelines

I am trying to update a file which is present inside my Linux VM from a pipeline. Each time I'm getting one or the other syntax error. I'm doing this using Python.

```
def get_awk_command():
    return """cd /test/tlu; awk '{sub(/SampleUrl=.*/, "SampleUrl=https://google.com/api")}1' config.properties > config.tmp && mv config.tmp config.properties -f"""


async def update_config(args, project_name):
     update_config_command = get_awk_command().replace("'", r"'\''")
     gcp_command = f'gcloud compute ssh testuser@{VM_NAME} --project={project_name} --zone={vm_zone} --tunnel-through-iap --quiet --command=\"sudo bash -c {update_config_command}\"'
     process = subprocess.run(gcp_command, shell=True, capture_output=True)
     output =  process.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

All indentations are correct. I think it is failing due to the way which the command is constructed. Please help to solve this.

The error I'm getting is

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Please share the error you recieved for this piece of code.

Comment: Thanks @Sparrow. I have edited the question with error message

Comment: Why are you using python to run shell commands instead of just running shell commands?

Comment: @DanielMann, I have to run a script parallelly on many gcp projects. So I choose python. This is only a part of the script.

Comment: Do you need to use bash commands? Why not just open and edit the file using Python, like with `open` and `re.sub`?

Answer (score 0):

Your quoting is incorrect. By far the simplest fix is to avoid quoting altogether by avoiding `shell=True`. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess); but this is still really complex because of the multiple levels of nesting (`ssh` calling `sudo` calling `bash -c`).  I don't have any way to test this, but try something like this:

```
def get_awk_command():
    return """cd /test/tlu
    awk '{sub(/SampleUrl=.*/, "SampleUrl=https://google.com/api")}1' config.properties > config.tmp &&
    mv config.tmp config.properties -f"""

async def update_config(args, project_name):
     update_config_command = get_awk_command().replace("'", r"'\''")
    process = subprocess.run([
        'gcloud', 'compute', 'ssh', f'testuser@{VM_NAME}',
        f'--project={project_name}', f'--zone={vm_zone}',
        '--tunnel-through-iap', '--quiet',
        "--command=sudo bash -c '{update_config_command}'"
        ],
    capture_output=True,
    # also add this to avoid having to explicitly decode()
    text=True)
    output = process.stdout
```

The argument to `bash -c` needs to be a single string, which usually requires quoting. Replacing the single quotes in the command you want to run is a rather clumsy workaround, but in this scenario, I guess you just have to push through.

By removing `shell=True` I have peeled off one layer which requires quoting, so this is slightly simpler. If you wanted to insist on `shell=True` you would have to figure out a way to quote every quote construction one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to write command lines into a shell script (**`.sh`**), then call this script file in the Python code.

For example:

- MyShellScript.sh

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash

  cat config.properties
  awk '{gsub(/SampleUrl=.*/,"SampleUrl=https://google.com/api"); print > "config.properties" }' config.properties
  cat config.properties
  ```
- MyPythonScript.py

  ```
  import subprocess

  subprocess.run(["chmod", "+x", "./MyShellScript.sh"])
  subprocess.run(["./MyShellScript.sh"], shell=True)
  ```